# .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Tags: python, dataframe, syntax-error

I dont really understand how to apply the suggested fix, any help would be appreciated.

Error:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.

Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

analytics_df['HDD_{}'.format(i)] = analytics_df['Min24 Hour'].apply(

Comment: Just replace the line `analytics_df['HDD_{}'.format(i)] = ...` with `analytics_df.loc[:,'HDD_{}'.format(i)] = ...`, and make a similar change to the adjusted_HDD line.

Comment: Also, is the message that you got an *error* or is it a *warning*? If your code didn't stop running at that line, then it's a warning rather than an error.

Comment: Well I thought that was the error, but perhaps that was just the warning which is what confused me.    Pycharm also says: KeyError: 'Minimum Temperature 24 hour (C)'
So this must not have been the issue

Comment: Ok, so **that** would be the reason your program stopped. The error is telling you that there is no column called 'Minimum Temperature 24 hour (C)' in analytics_df, so you'll have to see why that's the case